# SSRS 2005: Group page numbers resetting, view xx from xx

Tags: sql-server, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

On SQL Server 2005, Reporting services I have printed form (e.g. `invoice`), which can be multi-page. I need to print a lot of such forms (e.g. all `invoices` for specified customer and for specific period) by one click. I put the layout in the table and group all info by the invoice number, so for the whole printed form it's fine, I've got, what I want. For all, except page numbering. Each invoice, if it's multi-page, should have in the footer page numbering like `page xx from xx`.

Is it possible to calculate the total number of pages for the group?

Answer (score 7):

The blog post *[Reset Page Number On Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chrishays/)* describes how to reset the page number at the end of each group. It simply requires a small custom code function and an expression for the page number.

In summary (quoted from the article):

> Step 1:  Make sure there's a textbox in the report which contains the
> group expression
>
> Step 2:  Add shared variables to track the current group and page
> offset
>
> ```
> Shared offset as Integer
> Shared currentgroup as Object
> ```
>
> Step 3:  Add a custom function to set the shared variables and
> retrieve the group page number
>
> ```
>  Public Function GetGroupPageNumber(group as Object, pagenumber as Integer) as Object
>    If Not (group = currentgroup)
>      offset = pagenumber - 1
>      currentgroup = group
>    End If
>    Return pagenumber - offset
>  End Function
> ```
>
> Step 4: Use the function in the page header or footer
>
> ```
> =Code.GetGroupPageNumber(ReportItems!Category.Value,Globals!PageNumber)
> ```

SSRS 2008 - For those finding this link in response to the newer versions of the report server information about this same issue can be found here:
[MSDN Blog - Reset Page Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/robertbruckner/report-design-reset-page-number-on-group)

Comment: in fact, no. It's popular article, it helps to reset the counter, but the problem with calculation the number of pages still doesn't solved ;) anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Quoting from the article is fair as it gets across the essence of the solution.

Comment: Sorry to dig this back up.  I have had very limited success with this particular article.  It is very promising, but it simply doesn't work in all cases.  For example, if you have a grouping row that generates a random number of pages.

Comment: @Matt - that's good feedback. What you can do is if you have some changes due to particular scenarios, you can either add another answer below or you can edit my answer to include them. If you do edit this answer then make a comment on this answer like you just did so that I get notified and I can assist with approving the edit. Older questions/answers like this don't accumulate much rep, but they are invaluable to the few people who do stumble across them, so if you have suggestions/advice then jump in and add it :)

Comment: @slugster I added information regarding the same exact issues resolution on the newer server.  Was thinking someone could leverage that and maybe backfill a solution to my particular issue.  Hopefully someone will find the entire thread useful in that rare case.